# How to set the namespace on serialization when property's namespace is empty?

Tags: c#, xml

I have 4 different namespaces and I add them as follows

```
var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
namespaces.Add("abc", "urn:abc");
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, "urn:efg");
namespaces.Add("xyz", "urn:xyz");
```

My object looks like this (small example):

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:abc")]
public class RootDocument
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    //No namespace here
    public SomeNode SomeNode { get; set; }
}

public class SomeNode 
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:xyz")]
    public OtherNode { get; set; }
}

public class OtherNode
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The class `SomeNode` is an example of a class that has no namespace. I have over 50 classes with lots of properties and I want to avoid setting a namespace on each and every one of them.

When I serialize the above I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<abc:RootDocument xmlns="urn:efg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xyz="urn:xyz" xmlns:abc="urn:abc">
    <abc:Header>
        <abc:SomeNode>
            <xyz:OtherNode>true</xyz:OtherNode>
        </abc:SomeNode>
    </abc:Header>
</abc:RootDocument
```

However, the output must be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<abc:RootDocument xmlns:efg="urn:efg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xyz="urn:xyz" xmlns:abc="urn:abc">
    <abc:Header>
        <efg:SomeNode>
            <xyz:OtherNode>true</xyz:OtherNode>
        </efg:SomeNode>
    </abc:Header>
</abc:RootDocument
```

Can I automatically set the namespace during serialization to `efg` on all nodes that have an empty workspace (ie. the properties don't have the `Namespace` of the `XmlElement` set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the namespace on runtime you have the [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.add?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The XmlAttributes object contains a union of attribute objects that
>   cause the XmlSerializer to override its default serialization behavior
>   for a set of objects. You choose the attribute objects to place in the
>   XmlAttributes object, depending on the particular behaviors you want
>   to override. For example, the XmlSerializer serializes a class member
>   as an XML element by default. If you want the member to be serialized
>   as an XM attribute instead, you would create an XmlAttributeAttribute,
>   assign it to the XmlAttribute property of an XmlAttributes, and add
>   the XmlAttributes object to the XmlAttributeOverrides object.
>
> **Use this overload to override an XmlRootAttribute or XmlTypeAttribute.**

For example:

```
public class Group
{
   public string GroupName;
   [XmlAttribute]
   public int GroupCode;
}

  public class Sample
  {
    public XmlSerializer CreateOverrider()
    {
       // Create an XmlAttributeOverrides object. 
       XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

       /* Create an XmlAttributeAttribute to override the base class
       object's XmlAttributeAttribute object. Give the overriding object
       a new attribute name ("Code"). */
       XmlAttributeAttribute xAtt = new XmlAttributeAttribute();
       xAtt.AttributeName = "Code";

       /* Create an instance of the XmlAttributes class and set the 
       XmlAttribute property to the XmlAttributeAttribute object. */
       XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
       attrs.XmlAttribute = xAtt;

       /* Add the XmlAttributes object to the XmlAttributeOverrides
          and specify the type and member name to override. */
       xOver.Add(typeof(Group), "GroupCode", attrs);

       XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group), xOver);
       return xSer;
    }
  }
```

And another one, with `XmlSerializerNamespaces`:

```
[XmlRoot("Node", Namespace="http://somenamepsace")]
public class MyType {
    [XmlElement("childNode")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("myNamespace", "http://somenamepsace");
        XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
        xser.Serialize(Console.Out, new MyType(), ns);
    }
}
```